# Can't size controller when launching RedLaser overlay view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am using the RedLaser SDK.  My app is a split view. I'm trying to launch a RedLaser overlay when a barbutton is pressed on the master view controller.

The method gets called when the button is pressed and that's where the problems start.  I have 3 different versions of the code that launches the overlay.  Each has it's own problem.

Option 1
This was my baseline and I knew it wouldn't work because I hadn't initialized the overlay.  The following code launches the view controller correctly but (obviously) doesn't do what I want.

```
     // Working Code that brings up dialog but doesn't start camera overlay
SRSScanVINViewController *scanVINViewController y= [[SRSScanVINViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:scanVINViewController];
[navController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
[navController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

Option 2
This code initiates the overlay controller and launches it without crashing.  The overlay is working and the camera is active.  The problem is that the viewcontroller/overlay is taking the whole screen.  My controls (buttons, etc) are all layed out as if the view controller is taking a portion of the upper-left portion of the screen.  This would work if I could get the overlay to be sized correctly.

```
      // Working code that shows the overlay (camera on) but the overlay takes the whole screen
SRSScanVINViewController *scanVINViewController = [[SRSScanVINViewController alloc] init];
[pickerController setOverlay:scanVINViewController];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:scanVINViewController];
[navController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
[navController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
[self presentViewController:pickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

Option 3
This attempt was to fix the problems in option 2 (above).  Here is the code:

```
     SRSScanVINViewController *scanVINViewController = [[SRSScanVINViewController alloc] init];
[pickerController setOverlay:scanVINViewController];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:pickerController];
[navController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
[navController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
[self presentViewController:pickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

It crashes with the following error (nslog):

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:      'Application tried to present modally an active controller <SRSMasterViewController:      0x1f59f540>.'
 *** First throw call stack:
 (0x37ecb88f 0x331fc259 0x30d86441 0x7f6b5 0x7edf7 0x37e253fd 0x30cbfe07 0x30d855e7      0x37e253fd 0x30cbfe07 0x30cbfdc3 0x30cbfda1 0x30cbfb11 0x30cc0449 0x30cbe92b 0x30cbe319      0x30ca4695 0x30ca3f3b 0x3630522b 0x37e9f523 0x37e9f4c5 0x37e9e313 0x37e214a5 0x37e2136d      0x36304439 0x30cd2cd5 0x7deb5 0x7de50)
 terminate called throwing an exception
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got the code to work but still have a couple of issues.  Here's the code:

```
     SRSScanVINViewController *scanVINViewController = [[SRSScanVINViewController alloc] init];
[pickerController setOverlay:scanVINViewController];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:scanVINViewController];
[navController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
[navController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    pickerControllerPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:pickerController];
    [pickerControllerPopover setDelegate:self];
    [pickerControllerPopover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320.0f, 460.0f)];
    [pickerControllerPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:NO];
}
else
{
    [self presentViewController:pickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This sets the size of the popover to the same size as my original controller (defined in the nib).  I still have a couple of issues though.

The controller has 4 buttons in a button bar at the bottom.  It also has a UIImage.  The first time I load this controller, the buttons (and button bar and UIImage) are either missing are located in strange places.  If I dismiss the popover controller by touching the screen somewhere outside of the controller and load the controller again, the controls are all in the right places.  In fact, they are in the right places every time EXCEPT the first time.

Any ideas?

Comment: Figured it out:  I went into the NIB and deselected "Autoresize Subviews" and now it shows correctly every time.